# How to find id of dynamically created jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

So my task is to add a new row in grid created using jqGrid dynamically. Now I did some study and saw this method: 
$("#grid").addRowData(rowid,data, position, srcrowid);

but to use above method I need to first find out what id("#grid") has been given to my grid.

when I am trying to inspect elements I see elements such as :

```
   <div style="width: 1030px;" dir="ltr" id="gbox_grid-34e0dc5c-e79e-4011-80c8-30f8f0dbf61c" class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   .....
   ....
       <div style="width: 1030px;" id="gview_grid-34e0dc5c-e79e-4011-80c8-30f8f0dbf61c" class="ui-jqgrid-view">
           ....All Grid data....
       </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
var gridID = $(".ui-jqgrid").attr("id");
```